# Is my understanding of Hashsets correct?(Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I'm teaching myself data structures through this python book and I'd appreciate if someone can correct me if I'm wrong since a hash set seems to be extremely similar to a hash map.

**Implementation:**
A Hashset is a list [] or array where each index points to the head of a linkedlist

So some hash(some_item) --> key, and then list[key] and then  add to the head of a LinkedList. This occurs in O(1) time

When removing a value from the linkedlist, in python we replace it with a placeholder because hashsets are not allowed to have Null/None values, correct?

When the list[] gets over a certain % of load/fullness, we copy it over to another list

**Regarding Time Complexity Confusion:**
So one question is, why is Average search/access O(1) if there can be a list of N items at the linkedlist at a given index?

**Wouldnt the average case be the searchitem is in the middle of its indexed linkedlist so it should be O(n/2) -> O(n)?**

Also, when removing an item, if we are replacing it with a placeholder value, isn't this considered a waste of memory if the placeholder is never used?

And finally, what is the difference between this and a HashMap other than HashMaps can have nulls? And HashMaps are key/value while Hashsets are just value?

Comment: Comparing a HashSet and a LinkedList is probably a poor choice. A Set doesn't allow duplicates. A HashSet computes the hash of the elements to determine similarities.

Comment: Isn't hashing with chaining a linked solution to deal with collision?

Comment: In theory, yes, but collisions in a Python `set()` do not chain. Collisions are overwritten

Comment: Collisions just mean that their hashes are the same, not that they are duplicates, so they can't just be overwritten. A set does allow duplicate hash values.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question - why is the average time complexity of a lookup O(1)? - this statement is in general only true if you have a good hash function. An ideal hash function is one that causes a nice spread on its elements. In particular, hash functions are usually chosen so that the probability that any two elements collide is low. Under this assumption, it's possible to formally prove that the expected number of elements to check is O(1). If you search online for "universal family of hash functions," you'll probably find some good proofs of this result.

As for using placeholders - there are several different ways to implement a hash table. The approach you're using is called "closed addressing" or "hashing with chaining," and in that approach there's little reason to use placeholders. However, other hashing strategies exist as well. One common family of approaches is called "open addressing" (the most famous of which is linear probing hashing), and in those setups placeholder elements are necessary to avoid false negative lookups. Searching online for more details on this will likely give you a good explanation about why.

As for how this differs from HashMap, the HashMap is just one possible implementation of a map abstraction backed by a hash table. Java's HashMap does support nulls, while other approaches don't.

Comment: I understand that linear probing is searching for the next open index using a constant to avoid collision, which can have O(n) complexity if the next open index is at the end of the list. But a placeholder is necessary in a hash set yes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "placeholder?" Also, when you say "hash set," are you referring to the specific setup you talked about in your question?

Comment: Note: If you're talking about Python (at least, the CPython reference interpreter), it's based on open addressing, so no linked list-like structures are involved (but it does have dummy entries that serve as placeholders when an entry is deleted; they're necessary so that a future lookup for an element that collided further along can be found, instead of stopping when it hits a truly empty slot).

Comment: From my understanding, when removing a hashed key from the "chaining method", we cannot have Null/None values in a Hashed Set and we can't delete the chained node or else we would lose reference to the other nodes in the same chain, so the solution is to put a placeholder there to mark it avaliable

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm trying to understand both implementations of Hash Sets (open addressing and chaining) using Python for general knowledge, not just the interpreter version but I'm using Python as my language to try to implement both.

Comment: @driftdrift: With the chaining method, you don't need placeholders, because it's easy to remove an element from the middle of the linked list and connect the elements on either side (it's `O(1)`, no connection to length of linked list or the size of the `set` as a whole). You need the placeholders in open addressing because there would be indeterminate (as high as `O(n)` in the size of the whole `set`) work involved in ensuring all possible chain sequences intersecting that bucket remained consistent.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't understand why its O(1) if its in the middle of the linked list. I thought you needed to traverse the linked list to find the value, so the worst case would be O(N) if its at the end of the chain, and the average case would be O(N/2) if its in the middle. Why does this resolve to O(1) if it's not pointed to by the head or tail?

Comment: By linked list, do you mean the chain of colliding elements within the hash table, not a separate data structure in each bucket?

Comment: @driftdrift: It's `O(n)` in the length of the linked list to find the value, `O(1)` to remove it. But either way, assuming a good hash function, the number of collisions in any given bucket should be single digits, regardless of the number of values in the hash; even `O(n)` in size of the bucket's values isn't a big deal, so the bucket's values rarely exceed half a dozen.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup time wouldn't be `O(n)` because not all items need to be searched, it also depends on the number of buckets. More buckets would decrease the probability of a collision and reduce the chain length.

The number of buckets can be kept as a constant factor of the number of entries by resizing the hash table as needed. Along with a hash function that evenly distributes the values, this keeps the expected chain length bounded, giving constant time lookups.

The hash tables used by hashmaps and hashsets are the same except they store different values. A hashset will contain references to a single value, and a hashmap will contain references to a key and a value. Hashsets can be implemented by delegating to a hashmap where the keys and values are the same.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding now from searching around. What I am talking about is known as a "LinkedHashSet" in Java, it is used in the "chaining method". The average time is O(1) because there should not be a lot of collisions, thus the linkedlist at each index should be very short. I was saying O(N) under the assumption that there would be a lot of collisions but this is not the way to design a hash table but O(N) would be the worst case

Answer (score 0):

A lot has been written here about open hash tables, but some fundamental points are missed.

Practical implementations generally have O(1) lookup and delete because they guarantee buckets won't contain more than a fixed number of items (the *load factor*). But this means they can only achieve *amortized* O(1) time for insert because the table needs to be reorganized periodically as it grows.

(Some may opt to reorganize on delete, also, to shrink the table when the load factor reaches some bottom threshold, gut this only affect space, not asymptotic run time.)

Reorganization means increasing (or decreasing) the number of buckets and re-assigning all elements into their new bucket locations. There are schemes, e.g. *extensible hashing*, to make this a bit cheaper. But in general it means touching each element in the table.

Reorganization, then, is O(n). How can insert be O(1) when any given one may incur this cost? The secret is amortization and the power of powers.  When the table is grown, it *must* be grown by a *factor* greater than one, two being most common.  If the table starts with 1 bucket and doubles each time the load factor reaches F, then the cost of N reorganizations is

```
F + 2F + 4F + 8F ... (2^(N-1))F = (2^N - 1)F
```

At this point the table contains `(2^(N-1))F` elements, the number in the table during the last reorganization. I.e. we have done `(2^(N-1))F` inserts, and the total cost of reorganization is as shown on the right.  The interesting part is the *average* cost per element in the table (or insert, take your pick):

```
(2^N - 1)F      2^N
---------- ~= ------- = 2
(2^(N-1))F    2^(N-1)
```

*That's* where the amortized O(1) comes from.

One additional point is that for modern processors, linked lists aren't a great idea for the bucket lists. With 8-byte pointers, the overhead is meaningful. More importantly, heap-allocated nodes in a single list will almost never be contiguous in memory.  Traversing such a list kills cache performance, which can slow things down by orders of magnitude.

Arrays (with an integer count for number of data-containing elements) are likely to work out better. If the load factor is small enough, just allocate an array equal in size to the load factor at the time the first element is inserted in the bucket. Otherwise, grow these element arrays by factors the same way as the bucket array! Everything will still amortize to O(1).

To delete an item from such a bucket, don't mark it deleted. Just copy the last array element to the location of the deleted one and decrement the element count. Of course this won't work if you allow external pointers into the hash buckets, but that's a bad idea anyway.